# SQL Database with Remote Connections

Tags: sql, database

Hello I am looking for a little Direction / Guidance.  I have built an application in vb.net using visual studio for my company that manages people and equipment.  This application is installed on multiple computers in the office and updates a Microsoft Access Database which resides on one of our local Network Servers in the Building.  What my goal for this is to have the application access the database from any location in or out of the network.  I originally built this around an Access Database because it seemed the easiest at the time, I would like to re-create this in an SQL Database but am unsure how to and or what I need to do so I have this access with the application.  I am confused to how the SQL database would work with the remote access I guess.. Do I need to have an SQL Engine installed on the Server or can I have the Database file just sitting there and access it through the IP with Username and Passwords? Should I purchase server space somewhere else and go that route?  Is there any links or information anyone could direct me to, I have been reading about this for days but am not getting anywhere.. Just looking for some black and white answers to steer me in the right direction!!

Thanks Everyone!

Comment: SQL Server installs a 'service'. Connections to the database talk only to the 'service' and the service in turn takes care of communicating with the database files in a consistent way. In MS Access every user needs to have a full version of MS Access installed, and the users client machine talks directly to the database file, not via a service. With multiple abritrary clients talking directly to a file, there is more chance of a corrupted database or inconsistent data. Also all of the 'work' is done on the client machine, not on the server.

Comment: The other thing to remember is the data access library for MS Access is usually JET, which has it's own set of libraries. When you switch to SQL you need to use the SQL libraries, which work differently, so you need to rewrite it, but it is well worth it.

Comment: Thanks Nick! I did notice data was getting sort of mismatched in the Access Database, I'm not too sure if I possibly had the Keys set up incorrectly.. But I am currently working with approximately 40 Tables In the access database getting between rows 400 - 500 the data is mixed up a lot.  I should have just taken the time to learn SQL and go that route from the get go!

Comment: It's all a learning experience.... now you have some experience with Access under your belt you have an idea what it's ideal uses are.

Comment: Just thought I would give an update today Even though this is closed.. I went with Azure and it does absolutely everything I need it to, I am very happy with the simplicity and friendliness of it!  Once again thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend Azure.  This article describes the process for migrating from Access to Azure:

[Migrating Access Databases to SQL Server/Azure SQL DB (AccessToSQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh313051(v=sql.110).aspx)

Comment: Good call. But a single URL answers are discouraged. Can you summarize what the doc says for future users please?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Jim I will look into this as well!

Answer (score 0):

All major SQL RDBMS client/server systems are built around the premise that clients will he accessing the relational database management services over a network (almost always over TCP/IP for anything developed or updated within the last couple of decades).

For the nodes (clients) on your local area network this should be relatively straightforward.

For remote access I strongly recommend requiring that they access your network through a quality VPN which has been professionally configured (and, preferably, is being professionally maintained).

As for the question of locally owned equipment vs. a virtually private server (VPS) that's mostly a cost consideration with tradeoffs on reliability of access, reliability of the hardware and storage, reliability and capacity of the backup systems, and the personnel costs and availability.

A well managed VPS offering can get you past all the preliminary hurdles to the point where you can focus on your development right away.  The long term decisions about Tue production environment are best deferred until you have some functionality prototyped.

Comment: I would prefer to purchase my own server space as I will not be limited to the functions of our company servers.  The IT Company they have hired here is horrendous!  Any suggestions on companies to purchase server space from? I would like to focus on the development of this product straight away as I am not overly familiar with VPN's and networking...